# Вывод изображения через минуту js

Tags: jquery, setinterval, javascript

хочу сделать картинку, которая показывается посетителю сайта через 1 минуту, а для выхода картинку нужно будет закрыть.
Начал писать код, но не получается. Вот мой код:

```
$(function(){

var intervalID;

intervalID=setTimeout(
function() {
    $('#i').css({display:"block"});
}, 500);
clearInterval(intervalID);


});
```

Comment: @Пашка Босой, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $img = $('#image');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $img.show();
    },60000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
setTimeout(function(){ // Тамер, который покажет картинку через 5 секунд.
  $('#image').fadeIn(400);
}, 5000); // Замените 5000 на 60000 (это 1 минута)

$('#image .close').on('click', function(){ // При нажатии на X окно с картинкой закроется.
  $('#image').fadeOut(300);
});
```

```css
#image {
  display: none;
  max-width: 100vw:
  max-height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#image .close {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#image img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Подождите 5 секунд и увидете картинку.

<div id="image">
  <div class="close">X</div>
  <img src="//i.imgur.com/52vpKiD.png">
  Нажмите X чтобы закрыть.
</div>
```